# Delete specific linebreaks with Word Interop

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, office-interop

i have Problems to delete some specific Linebreaks with word interop. It seems that the indexes of doc.Content.Text does not match with the ones of word..

I need to delete all breaks which has no dot as previous character.

With small documents it works, but only for about 3-5 breaks after that, the selected Range is not a pagebreak, anyone has an idea how to delete these breaks without range.select(start: start, end: end) or knows the problem?

**for example i have following text:**

*US investigators who looked at a poll of 340,000 people found moods were no worse on Mondays than other working days, bar Friday.((break))*

*People were happier as they approached the weekend, lending support for the concept of ((break to delete))*

*"that Friday feeling".((break))*

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

        word.Visible = true;

        string document = @"C:\bin\Debug\123.doc";

        if (document != null)
        {
            Document doc = word.Documents.Open(document, ReadOnly: false, Visible: true);
            doc.Activate();
            string text = doc.Content.Text;

            int index = text.IndexOf("\r");
            int deletetCount = 0;

            while(index != -1)
            {
                if (index != 0 && text[index - 1] != '.')
                {
                    int start = index + 1 - deletetCount;
                    int end = start + 1;
                    if (start >= 0 && end >= 0 && end > start)
                    {
                        Range range = doc.Range(Start: start, End: end);
                        range.Select();
                        range.Delete();
                        deletetCount++;
                    }
                }

                index = text.IndexOf("\r", index + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### i have found a solution:

Now i use Search & Replace with wildcards (Regex)

Rules for deleting breaks:

- previous char is not a dot or colon
- text is not bold (for my case bold text is mostly a heading)
- breaks with following text should not be deleted (listings): a. b. c. 1. 2. 3.
  --> to match listings they have to be converted to text (doc.ConvertNumbersToText())

.

```
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

        word.Visible = true;

        string document = @"C:\bin\Debug\1.doc";

        if (document != null)
        {
            Document doc = word.Documents.Open(document, ReadOnly: false, Visible: true);
            doc.Activate();

            object missingObject = null;

            doc.ConvertNumbersToText();

            object item = WdGoToItem.wdGoToPage;
            object whichItem = WdGoToDirection.wdGoToFirst;
            object replaceAll = WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
            object forward = true;
            object matchWholeWord = false;
            object matchWildcards = true;
            object matchSoundsLike = false;
            object matchAllWordForms = false;
            object wrap = WdFindWrap.wdFindAsk;
            object format = true;
            object matchCase = false;
            object originalText = "([!.:])^13(?[!.])";
            object replaceText = @"\1 \2";

            doc.GoTo(ref item, ref whichItem, ref missingObject, ref missingObject);
            foreach (Range rng in doc.StoryRanges)
            {
                rng.Find.Font.Bold = 0;

                rng.Find.Execute(ref originalText, ref matchCase,
            ref matchWholeWord, ref matchWildcards, ref matchSoundsLike, ref matchAllWordForms, ref forward,
            ref wrap, ref format, ref replaceText, ref replaceAll, ref missingObject,
            ref missingObject, ref missingObject, ref missingObject);
            }

        }
    }
}
```